# Infinite scroll FlatList headers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

In my react native app I use 2 endpoints of cocktailDB API:
https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list - drink categories
https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Ordinary%20Drink - drinks list

I made a `FlatList` that `onEndReached()` changes the page number and makes an API call to get drinks for a subsequent category. The drinks get added to the `drinksList` array so that the data from the previous API call remains on top.

```
       <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.idDrink.toString()}
          data={drinksList}
          onEndReached={() => {
            if (!isLoading) {
              setCurrentPage((page) => page + 1);
            }
          }}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.3}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <Image
                  style={{height: 100, width: 100, marginRight: 20}}
                  source={{uri: item.strDrinkThumb}}
                />
                <Text>{item.strDrink}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
```

I assigned array `index` as an `id` to each category item, so that I can get access to them based on the `currentPage` value.

My question is, how do I add a header to each drink category when it gets rendered after an API call. I tried doing it with `ListHeaderComponent` prop of `FlatList` but it didn't work cause there is only one `FlatList`, so the header changes but remains on the very top of the `FlatList` but I need that category name to be on top of each `FlatList` "page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SectionList instead of FlatList` which has multiple sections like you can say multiple headers.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the noob question, I'm kinda new to this

Comment: No worries bro.